# Uploading code to another TFS instance (VSTS)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

The other day I wanted to upload code on my laptop to my Visual Studio Team Services account.   The problem was that the code had been developed on a different TFS instance.

I found no way to connect to VSTS, with an already existing solution and just upload it, check it in.  Instead VSTS required me to create the solution there. Barring any major file copying I could not find a simple way to do this.

There's one other question similar to this on S.O. but it requires 3rd party intervention.  Shouldn't this be a simple matter?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the binding to the old TFS first, in VS2013(and 2010) it is here: File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> "Change Source Control...". Select each project in the list and click "Unbind" for each of them.
After that there shouldn't be a problem.